# Changing selectedImage on UITabBarItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I've been trying to change the selected image on a UITabBar. I've followed procedures listed on other Stackoverflow questions, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried setting the image through the User Defined Runtime Attributes section, as well as tried adding the following to AppDelegate.swift:

```
var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
let tabItems = tabBarController.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]

var selectedImage0 = UIImage(named:"NewsfeedTabSelected")
selectedImage0?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
tabItems[0].selectedImage = selectedImage0
```

This doesn't yield any results. I did a **println(tabItems[0].title)** and that output the correct title, so I know that the reference to the TabBarItem is working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using selected image in storyboard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The previous answer does not fully work.
I have to set the new `UIImage`'s `UIImageRenderingMode` to `AlwaysOriginal`, this solves my situation.

code bellow:

```
import UIKit

class MainTab: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    var tabBar = self.tabBar

    var homeSelectImage: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "firstPageSelected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    var qaSelectImage: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "Q&ASelected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    var mySelectImage: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "myBagSelected")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

    (tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem ).selectedImage = homeSelectImage
    (tabBar.items![1] as! UITabBarItem ).selectedImage = qaSelectImage
    (tabBar.items![2] as! UITabBarItem ).selectedImage = mySelectImage

    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

}
}
```

Hope that work for you

Comment: A big + to UIImageRenderingMode finally this took me to the solutions

Answer (score 11):

I solved using something like this on the AppDelegate.

```
var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
var tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar as UITabBar

var tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
var tabBarItem2 = tabBar.items![1] as UITabBarItem
var tabBarItem3 = tabBar.items![2] as UITabBarItem

tabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "FirstSelectedImage")
tabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "SecondSelectedImage")
tabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "ThirdSelectedImage")
```

Comment: But there is some bug in swift, because text of tabBarItem2 disappears, when I tap it.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass/extend tabBarController and implement these methods (I know it's obj-c but it should work as directly translated to swift):

```
#import "const.h"
#import "MainTabBarController.h"

@interface MainTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation MainTabBarController

- (NSArray*)tabTitles {
    return @[@"Connection",
             @"Details",
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastProfileResponse"] ? @"Profile" : @"Login",
             @"Settings"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"connection_tab_",
                            @"details_tab_",
                            @"profile_tab_",
                            @"settings_tab_"
                            ];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.tabBar.items.count; ++i) {
        ((UITabBarItem*)self.tabBar.items[i]).title = self.tabTitles[i];

        ((UITabBarItem*)self.tabBar.items[i]).selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames[i] stringByAppendingString:@"on"]];

        ((UITabBarItem*)self.tabBar.items[i]).image = [[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames[i] stringByAppendingString:@"off"]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    }

    self.tabBar.translucent = false;
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = SLATE_GREEN;
    self.tabBar.tintColor = YELLOW;
    self.delegate = self;

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:WHITE,
                                                                                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                                                                 TAB_FONT,
                                                                                                 NSFontAttributeName, nil]
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:YELLOW,
                                                                                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```